# How secure is SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to determine how secure the mechanism is. I cannot find information on whether it is 256-bit/1024/2048 encryption or something else that is more (less) secure. If it is not at least 1024, are there alternatives to use for an MVC application like SimpleMembershipProvider?

Comment: Maybe its me but can you elaborate your question? do you mean if the password is encrypted?

Comment: I guess I am looking to see how well the password is encrypted. If it meets a particular standard.